# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #5](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/5) on Travel has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Rory Alsop]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/5) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5198817214332928).

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations Rory Alsop, you'll do a great job!

Comment: Thanks Midavalo. I will do my best.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations Rory and welcome to the Moderator team! Do not hesitate to get in touch should you have any questions.

Midavalo, good effort as a runner-up! 102 votes is not at all bad.